# delete entire row of a table in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, delete-row

I have a table consist with several columns and rows. I have given a delete button to each row. How can i remove a entire row from this table?

my controller

```
;
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', []).controller('questionEditCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$http', function ($scope, $timeout, $http) {


            $scope.delete = function () {


                console.log("submit pressed");


            }


        }]);
})();
```

my view

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="questionEditCtrl">

    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name='quizEdit' ng-submit="submit(data)">
    <div class="table-responsive">          
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Questions</th>
                    <th>Answer 1</th>
                    <th>Answer 2</th>
                    <th>Answer 3</th>
                    <th>Answer 4</th>
                    <th>Answer 5</th>
                    <th>Correct Answer</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                foreach ($quizes as $q) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $q['question_id']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $q['question']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php
                            if (isset($q['answers'][0])) {
                                echo $q['answers'][0];
                            }
                            ?></td>
                        <td><?php
                            if (isset($q['answers'][1])) {
                                echo $q['answers'][1];
                            }
                            ?></td>
                        <td><?php
                            if (isset($q['answers'][2])) {
                                echo $q['answers'][2];
                            }
                            ?></td>
                        <td><?php
                            if (isset($q['answers'][3])) {
                                echo $q['answers'][3];
                            }
                            ?></td>
                        <td><?php
                    if (isset($q['answers'][4])) {
                        echo $q['answers'][4];
                    }
                    ?></td>
                        <td><?php
                    if (isset($q['correctAnswer'])) {
                        echo $q['correctAnswer'];
                    }
                    ?></td>
                        <td><a href="">Edit</a> / <a href="" ng-click="delete()">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I have gone through some tutorials but wasn't so clear.

Comment: You won't likely find much help in tutorials since you aren't using angular to create the rows which is how it would typically be done. The norm would be to pass your `quizzes` data to an angular controller and then simply splice the data array to remove the row. In your case you will need to do dom manipulation yourself by passing in the event

Comment: can u explain using an example?

Comment: look for tutorial that uses angular `ng-repeat` which would replace your php `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

First you would need some back-end code to actually delete the row. You would also need to use angular to create the table ([example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_tables.htm)). Assuming this is in place you could then do the following:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('questionEditCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$http', 'DataService', function ($scope, $timeout, $http, DataService) {
  $scope.delete = function () {
    console.log("submit pressed");

     $http.delete("/api/deleteRow", id).then( 
        function(results){
          // You can either remove the row from the array using splice:
          $scope.quizes.splice(id, 1;                

          // Or simply call refresh 
          $scope.refresh();
        });
  }
}]);
```

The above code has not been implemented, but should give you an outline of how it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to let angular manage the list of quizzes and let angular render the list.

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', []).controller('questionEditCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$http',
        function($scope, $timeout, $http) {
          var url = 'myurl';
          //get the quzes from service via $http.get
          $scope.quizes = [{
            question_id: 1,
            quesiton: "foo?"
          }, {
            question_id: 2,
            quesiton: "bar?"
          }];

          $scope.delete = function(quiz) {

            console.log("submit pressed");
            $http.delete(url, {
              id: quiz.question_id
            }).then(function() {
                //server delete was successful
                _.remove($scope.quizes, quiz); //using lodash

              }
            }


          }]);
    })();
```

```html
<div class="container" ng-controller="questionEditCtrl">

  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name='quizEdit' ng-submit="submit(data)">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Questions</th>
            <th>Answer 1</th>
            <th>Answer 2</th>
            <th>Answer 3</th>
            <th>Answer 4</th>
            <th>Answer 5</th>
            <th>Correct Answer</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

          <tr ng-repeat="quiz in quizes track by $index">
            <td>{{quiz.question_id}}</td>
            <td>{{quiz.question }}</td>
... simplified ...

            <td><a href="">Edit</a> / <a href="" ng-click="delete(quiz)">Delete</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```